# Moodle installation blank page returned

Tags: xampp, moodle

Trying to install moodle using xammp, i have tried this using moodle 2.6 and 2.7 and the same issue is occuring.

After the update admin profile page I get a blank screen returning, this should move onto the front page settings to complete the installation but this never appears, I refresh and get into the site only to find it does not work when navigating around and the site is unresponsive?

I have tried using Windows Server 2012 and Windows 8.1, and all browsers with different modes enabled and it fails every time.

Is this a moodle build issue or an issue with the OS or xammp? Even the standalone packaged versions that moodle supply fail?

Comment: Have you checked your php and mysql are meeting moodle's requirement, Validate from here. http://download.moodle.org/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably a php error but you will need to switch on debugging to see the message

Edit /config.php and add these 2 lines

```
$CFG->debug = 32767;
$CFG->debugdisplay = true;
```

and try again.

UPDATE:

You'll need to edit your php.ini file and change or add this line:

```
max_execution_time = 300 ; was 30
```

I'm using 5 minutes but you can change it to anything you like.

then restart Apache and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i got these errors? 
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\Users\Administrator.MTS0010\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\moodle\lib\dml\mysqli_native_moodle_database.php on line 1078

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\Users\Administrator.MTS0010\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\moodle\lib\classes\shutdown_manager.php on line 67

Comment: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\Users\Administrator.MTS0010\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\moodle\lib\dml\mysqli_native_moodle_database.php on line 1078

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\Users\Administrator.MTS0010\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\moodle\lib\classes\shutdown_manager.php on line 67

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error few days back. I tried the debug mode but it didn't helped. When you look at the url you get it has a query string
`?cache=1` or something which indicates something related to cache was the issue.

I deleted the cache manually from `$CFG->dataroot` [ path is   `c:/xampp/moodledata`  - your path may be different. Check your config.php file for the same]. Delete the content of `moodledata folder` and refresh your page. It should work